# Unable to add a transition to Bulma Calendar element

Tags: css, bulma

I've been trying to add a slide up transition into the [Bulma Calendar DateTime picker](https://demo.creativebulma.net/components/calendar/v6/demonstration/datetime/) for a while now, unsuccesfully. I need the calendar to slide into position instead of abruptly appearing into the screen. So far I've been testing adding the following code in various places:

```
transition: all 2s;
```

But for the life of me it won't work. Does anyone has at least a hint of what am I missing here?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `all` in your code. How I know, you just need to write your code as such :

```
transition: 2s;
```